# How to use SharedObject with two Document classes in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, flash-cs6, shared-objects, local-shared-object

I'm having trouble implementing `SharedObject` in my game.

My Main Document class `Engine` and a separate class called `mcEndGameScreen` and in this class which is linked to my Flash CS6 Document.

In my Flash Document there are two Text fields with an instance name of `finalScore` and `bestScore`.

What I want to accomplish is saving and loading the final current score that the player got at the end of the game and the overall best score. I want these values to be displayed of course on my `mcEndGameScreen`.

How I update and keep track of the Highscore which is displayed in the game as the user plays?

HighScore is in my Engine class like so:

```
//Text Fields
public var highScoreText:TextField;
public var nScore:Number;
```

In my Engine Function:

```
//Add Text fields to stage
stage.addChild(highScoreText);

//Add score to text field
nScore = 0; 
updateHighScore();
```

Then the highscore function:

```
public function updateHighScore():void
{
   highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + nScore;
}
```

Now, how would I go about sharing the scores and displaying them on my mcEndGameScreen? Also in my Engine I reference the screen like so:

```
public var menuEnd:mcEndGameScreen;
```

Then I just call the child when the game is over to load up.

But I was thinking of doing something like this in my Engine class maybe:

```
public var _sharedObject:SharedObject;
```

Then in my Engine constructor function:

```
_sharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myGame");
```

But honestly not too sure what to do after that? Or how to use the `public var finalScore:TextField` and `public var bestScore:TextField` with my main Engine class. Since they are linked to my mcEndGameScreen.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass highScore to `mcEndGameScreen` class then add new var and new setter function like so:

```
private var _highScore:String;

public function set highScore(value:String): ():Void {
    _highScore = value;
}
```

Now in `Engine` class set it like so:

```
menuEnd.highScore = String(nScore);
```

To store highScore in `SharedObject` do like so:

```
_sharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myGame");
_sharedObject.highScore = nScore;
_sharedObject.flush(); //Write to shared object
```

To access `highScore` stored in `SharedObject` like so:

```
menuEnd.highScore = _sharedObject.data.highScore;
```

Comment: Okay so when I add the set highScore function in my mcEndGameScreen class then i can access the highScore and use them with my finalScore and bestScore Text fields in my FLA?  How would I go about passing my highScore through the finalScore and bestScore textfields on my mcEndGameScreen class? Just a little confused about that. But thanks for the information. It helped a lot

Comment: I get this error when i try to use menuEnd.highScore = nScore;   Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type String.

Comment: It was type conversion (Number as a String). I have updated the answer.

Comment: Still a bit confused on how to pass the highscore from my engine class to my mcEndGameScreen classes text field. I have this so far public function bestScoreDisplay():void
  {
   bestScoreText.text = ("Best Score: " + )
  } But dont know what to add after the + sign

Comment: In which class `bestScoreDisplay():` is?

Comment: `bestScoreDisplay():void { bestScoreText.text = ("Best Score: " + bestScore.text) }`

Comment: bestScoreDisplay function is in my mcEndGameScreen class. my endgamescreen class has two text fields that are displayed in the FLA. which are the bestScoreText and finalScoreText

Comment: Thats why im trying to get the highScore from my Engine class and pass it to the textfields that are in my mcEndGameScreen class. Thanks for all your help by the way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47661/discussion-between-rajneesh-gaikwad-and-user2233653)